# How to hide PlaybackControls in AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, avplayer

Is there any other way to hide Playback controls except this line of code ?? `playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = false;`

Comment: tghere is only one option what options you need apart from this `playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = false`

Comment: why do you want to use something else?

Comment: Can you show the problem you are facing to use showsPlaybackControls propertie in your scenerio

Comment: becuase AVplayer comes from top left to full screen. I don't  know this line of code is the reason for that behaviour but, if I remove this line my video player plays fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the playback controls using the property showsPlaybackControls from [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVPlayerViewController/showsPlaybackControls) . 
You can refer the AVPlayerViewController reference class and can find the available properties to customize the player